# icons are not displayed properly after removing gnome

Tags: gnome, icons, xfce

I installed gnome on Xubuntu and after trying it for a few hours I tried to remove it from Xubuntu. After removing the gnome

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome*
```

some icons are not displayed. I can change the icons in the "Appearance" but when I chose my favourite icon set some of them are not displayed and I get a blank white thing instead of an icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome*
```

That is definitevly not the way to remove gnome or any oher desktop enviroment. Since you installed xubuntu you might wanna reinstall the xubuntu desktop package to install wathever you removed with the first comand.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

If you are planning to try other desktop enviroment in the future please check http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu

Comment: Yeah, it was not a good way to do it!
but how should I have to remove gnome?
I re-installed the xfce desktop. It did not resolve my rpoblem completely. I re-installed the theme and everything was back and works just fine.